# Node JS read Form Data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to send some attributes and a file to a Node JS application with multipart/form-data.

Client HTML Form:

```
<input id="picName" name="picName" class="form-control" placeholder="PicTitle..." style="border-radius: 1%; margin: 1%" type="name">
<form id="frmUploader" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/post/picture/" method="post">
<input id="file" type="file" name="picUploader" multiple /><br>
<input class="btn btn-md btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload" /><br>
</form>
```

Client JS:

```
$('#frmUploader').submit(function () {
      var username = localStorage.getItem("userName");
      var categoryName = $( "#categoryAddPic option:selected").text();
      var picTitle = $('#picName').val();

          var picture = $('input[name="picUploader"]').get(0).files[0];
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('picture', picture);
          formData.append('username', username);
          formData.append('categoryName', categoryName);
          formData.append('picTitle', picTitle);

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/post/picture',
                data: formData,
                headers:{
                    "Authorization": "bearer " + token
                },success:function (respond) {
                    ...
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Now I want to save the data of the form in my Node application. If it is necessary to know too, I´m using multer for saving the file on the server.

Thanks for help.

PS: The node version is 4.8.3

Node JS:

```
app.post('/post/picture',function (req, res, next) {

var picName = req.body.picName;
var username = req.body.username;
var displayPic = req.body.displayPic;
var createdAt = moment();
var updatedAt = moment();
var categoryName = req.body.categoryName;
var picIdForCat = null;

try {
    if (username) {
        upload(req, res, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.end("Something went wrong!");
            }
            //return res.end("File uploaded sucessfully!.");
            picName = pictureSaveFormat;
            var pictureCont = "./pictures/" + picName + ".jpg";

            User.findOne({
                where: {username: username}
            }).then(function (user) {
                var picture = {
                    picName: picName,
                    picture: pictureCont,
                    displayPic: null,
                    createdAt: createdAt,
                    updatedAt: updatedAt,
                    UserIdUser: user.idUser
                };
                Pictures.create(picture);

                if (categoryName) {
                    Pictures.findOne({
                        where: {picName: picture.picName}
                    }).then(function (pic) {
                        picIdForCat = pic.idPic;

                        Category.findOne({
                            where: {categoryName: categoryName}
                        }).then(function (category) {
                            var catId = category.idCat;
                            var catForPic = {PictureIdPic: picIdForCat, CategoryIdCat: catId};

                            CategorieForPic.create(catForPic);
                            //res.redirect('localhost:3000/index.Admin.html');
                            res.status(200).json({message: "Picture from: " + username + " with name: " + picName + " created with " + category.categoryName + "."});
                        })
                    }).catch(function (req, res, err) {
                        res.status(500).json({message: "Error: Adding Category to pic", reason: err});
                    });
                } else {
                    //res.redirect('localhost:3000/index.Admin.html');
                    res.status(200).json({message: "Picture from: " + username + " with name: " + picName + " created without a category."});
                }
            }).catch(next);
        });
    } else {
        res.status(404).json({message: "Not found.", reason: "A required parameter is missing."});
    }
}catch (err){
    res.status(500).json({message: "Fatal Server error: ", reason: err});
}
});
```

Comment: Can you also post nodejs code?

Comment: @null I tried it with body-parser, but that did not work

Answer (score 3):

When using a FormData object with jQuery.ajax, you have to set processData to false so that jQuery will not try to encode the FormData object and contentType to false so that jQuery will not set any content type headers. When FormData is used with ajax the proper content type header is generated for you.

```
     $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/post/picture',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            headers:{
                "Authorization": "bearer " + token
            },
            success:function (respond) {
                ...
            });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, and I can handle that request in Node normally with req.body?

Comment: You have to use multer to process it

Comment: Also, the names you used with the FormData object needs to match exactly on the server side

Answer (score 0):

headers: {
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
"Authorization": "bearer " + token
},
It was working on my side

Comment: Please add some text to describe how this answers the question